# Modular Visualization

Tags: graphics

I have this:

```
Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[π/2], Sin[π/2]}, {Cos[π/2], Sin[π/2]}}],
   Text["0", 1.2 {Cos[π/2], Sin[π/2]}],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[11 π/6], Sin[11 π/6]}, {Cos[11 π/6], Sin[11 π/6]}}],
   Text["1", 1.2 {Cos[11 π/6], Sin[11 π/6]}],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[7 π/6], Sin[7 π/6]}, {Cos[7 π/6], Sin[7 π/6]}}],
   Text["2", 1.2 {Cos[7 π/6], Sin[7 π/6]}]
 }, ImageSize -> 200
]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Now, I'd like to visualize `Mod[5, 3]`, starting with an arrow at $0$, then rotating around the outside of the circle in the clockwise direction, counting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as I pass each tick number, then halting the arrow.

And I think the preference would be that the distance of the arrow from the center of the circle increases as I move so it doesn't overly itself as it goes.

Any suggestions?

**Update** I managed to do this:

```
modularcount = Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[\[Pi]/2], Sin[\[Pi]/2]}, {Cos[\[Pi]/2], 
      Sin[\[Pi]/2]}}],
   Text["0", 0.8 {Cos[\[Pi]/2], Sin[\[Pi]/2]}],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[11 \[Pi]/6], Sin[11 \[Pi]/6]}, {Cos[11 \[Pi]/6], 
      Sin[11 \[Pi]/6]}}],
   Text["1", 0.8 {Cos[11 \[Pi]/6], Sin[11 \[Pi]/6]}],
   Line[{0.9 {Cos[7 \[Pi]/6], Sin[7 \[Pi]/6]}, {Cos[7 \[Pi]/6], 
      Sin[7 \[Pi]/6]}}],
   Text["2", 0.8 {Cos[7 \[Pi]/6], Sin[7 \[Pi]/6]}]
   }, ImageSize -> 200];
plt = PolarPlot[1.1 + 0.03 t, {t, Pi/2, Pi/2 + 10 Pi/3},
    PlotStyle -> Red] /. Line -> Arrow;
Show[modularcount, plt,
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.2}}]}]]
```

I've put the numbers inside. Which gives this image:

[image]

So I have a good solution when moving counterclockwise, but I haven't figured out how to go clockwise yet.

**Second Update:** Thanks to Quantum_Oli, I now have this:

```
Show[modularcount, Graphics[First[plt] /. {x_, y_} :> {-x, y}],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.2}}]}]]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Comment: One simply (kinda hack-y) way would be to replace `plt` in your `Show` with `Graphics[First[plt] /. {x_, y_} :> {-x, y}]`. Saves having to change anything else.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Thanks, that works. See my update to the original post.

Comment: David: If that solves your problem, why not make a self-answer instead of editing the solution into the question? (Or let @Quantum_Oli post it.)

Comment: You may be interested in ``Experimental`AngularSlider[2/5 Pi 16 ]``

Answer (score 9):

So the quick hack I posted in the comment works:

```
Graphics[First[plt] /. {x_, y_} :> {-x, y}]
```

Just negates the x coordinate of all the values on the line, thus reflecting the spiral in the y-axis. However it is a bit hacky.

You can with a little maths just find the end points of your spiral such that you can use the default counterclockwise behaviour, draw the spiral backwards as it were:

```
m = 5;
n = 3;

{tmin, tmax} = \[Pi]/2 + {(-2 \[Pi] Mod[m, n])/n, 2 \[Pi] Floor[m/n]};

Graphics[{
  Circle[],
  Table[
   With[{pos = {Cos[\[Pi]/2 - ( 2 \[Pi] i)/n], Sin[\[Pi]/2 - ( 2 \[Pi] i)/n]}}, {
     Line[{0.9 pos, pos}],
     Text[ToString@i, 0.8 pos]
     }], {i, 0, n - 1}],
  {Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0}],
   First@PolarPlot[1.1 + 0.2 (1 - (t - tmin)/(tmax - tmin)), {t, tmin, tmax}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red] /. Line -> Arrow
   }
  }
 ]
```

[image]

I've rewritten your code such that it will work for all `m` and `n`:

```
m = 22;
n = 7;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using @Quantum_Oli's nice generalization in an alternative way:

```
ppF = With[{tmin = π/2 - 2 π Mod[##]/#2, 
            tmax = π/2 + 2 π Floor[Divide@##], 
            epilog = Table[With[{pos = {Cos[π/2 - 2 π i/#2], Sin[π/2 - 2 π i/#2]}},
             {Line[{0.9 pos, pos}], Text[ToString@i, 0.8 pos]}], {i, 0, #2 - 1}],
            h = Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}]}]},
    PolarPlot[{1, 1.1 + 0.2 (1 - (t - tmin)/(tmax - tmin))}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
     Axes -> False, Epilog -> epilog,
     PlotStyle -> {Black, ({Arrowheads[{{.01, 1, h}, {-0.05, 0}}], Red, Arrow@@#} &)}]] &;

ppF[16, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An alternative way to change the direction:

```
reflectF = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]] &, #, {1}] &;


reflectF[ppF[14, 6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Just a different visualization.

```
    clock[n_, t_, tmax_] := Module[{c},
  c = {Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
    Red,
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, 
      0.7 {Sin[Mod[t, n] 2 Pi/n], Cos[2 Pi  Mod[t, n]/n]}}], {Red,
     ChartElementData[
       "BezelSector"][{{Pi/2 - 2 Pi t/n, Pi/2}, {1, 
        1 + 0.1 Floor[Quotient[t, n]]}}, 0]},
    Black, 
    Table[{Text[ n j/(2 Pi), 0.8 {Sin[j], Cos[j]}], 
      Line[{0.9 {Sin[j], Cos[j]}, {Sin[j], Cos[j]}}]}, {j, 
      0, (n - 1) 2 Pi/n, 2 Pi/n}], Orange,
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1 + 0.1 #] & /@ 
     Range[Floor[Quotient[tmax, n] - 1]]};
  Column[{Graphics[c, ImageSize -> 200],
    Row[Style[#, Bold, Blue, 16, FontFamily -> "Kartika"] & /@ {t, 
       " = "  , 
       Sequence @@ ({#1, "\[Times]", n, "+", #2} & @@ 
          QuotientRemainder[t, n]), " \[Congruent] ", Mod[t, n], 
       " mod ", n}]
    }, Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]
  ]
```

Visualizing (exporting the following as gif):

```
tab = Table[
   Row[{clock[3, t, 35], clock[5, t, 35], clock[7, t, 35]}], {t, 0, 
    35, 1}];
```

Note clock 1 and 2 are in phase twice after start (15,30) and clock 2 and 3 only once at 35 ticks.

[image]